# Are there any shortcuts for creating a table variable to match the columns in a view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view, types

I frequently need to create table variables within procedures, to store the top 25 rows from a view for processing.

I need to store these small batches in variables temporarily, because I'm performing numerous operations that modify data within the underlying tables, and some of these operations cause the rows to no longer appear within the view itself based on the view criteria (this is by design).

I need to keep the data around for the entire processing session, and I can't rely on the view itself to remain consistent through the operation.

The problem is, since we're doing this in many instances across multiple databases, if we ever make any changes to the columns in any of our views, the code becomes somewhat bug-prone since we also have to make sure to modify the relevant table types as well - without making any typos or mistakes, or overlooking anything.

So my question is, can we just declare table variables (or table types, if necessary) by just stating "Match the current columns in this view?"

That would make things much easier, since it would automatically keep all relevant table variables in sync with the current layout of the views in question, and eliminate the headache that comes with trying to keep it all straight manually.

If no such shortcut exists, then I guess we'll just have to create custom table types matching our views as needed, to at least keep it as centralized as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the usage of type variable could be replaced by [Temporary Table](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186986%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) something like:

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM myView
```

Will do the job perfectly.

With SELECT INTO, the table will be created with colomn and metadata avialable in you select statement.

Hope this helps.